# Unity - Prefab GUID and GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, guid

I was considering making a pooling system using the prefab GUID as keys in dictionary. One issue I'm having tho is getting the "original" GUID or prefab from an instance of it.

```
AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier()
```

Works fine when handing it a reference to the original, but not on instances.

```
PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource()
```

Should return the original prefab, but it always returns null (unless its handed a reference to the original in which case it just returns itself).

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember. PrefabUtility is only working in Editor, not in the game itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource.html

that method need an argument to work.
And like Kaffi said it's only working in the Editor (PrefabUtility is in UnityEditor class).

Comment: I was passing it the gameObject assuming it would find the original prefab, but as you both said most examples tend to show it used in editor scripts. Was kinda hoping I had a way of accessing the GUID of the original prefab but reading a blog on unity seems to indicate people creating their owns systems for that https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/19/spotlight-team-best-practices-guid-based-references/